# Segmentation Fault in SDL_FillRect

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault, sdl-2

I'm using the SDL2 library, in C.

I made a test program to open a white window, but I get a segmentation fault with the function SDL_FillRect even though there are no errors or warnings when I build it.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

static const int window_width = 1000;
static const int window_height = 1000;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //Window
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;

    //Window Surface where things will be shown
    SDL_Surface *surface = NULL;

    //Inicializar SDL
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == -1)
    {
        printf("Failed to initialize SDL2. SDL Error: %s", SDL_GetError());
    }
    else
    {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, window_width, window_height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if(window == NULL)
            printf("Failed to create SDL2 window. SDL Error: %s", SDL_GetError());
        else
        {
            //Fill window with white color
            SDL_FillRect(surface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(surface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));
            //Update surface with new changes
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
            //Wait before closing (parameter in miliseconds)
            SDL_Delay(4000);
        }
    }
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are passing in **surface** (which is set to **NULL**) as the first parameter to SDL_FillRect, may be the problem https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_FillRect

Comment: Hmm, ok. How should I pass it then?

Comment: Create a surface as shown in the example code in the link. **SDL_Surface *surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, window_width, window_height, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);**

Comment: "even though there are no errors or warnings when I build it..."  Be prepared for this to continue.  Most of the errors you'll see are errors like this, where you won't get any errors when you build the program, but the program is still wrong and works incorrectly when you run it.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the heads up. True story, not the first time something like that happened, alright. Anyway, my comment to the answer below explains what I did wrong

Answer (score 2):

You get Segmentation fault because `surface` is still `NULL`

This example code taken directly from the SDL wiki (https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_FillRect) shows how to create a `SDL_Surface` before calling `SDL_FillRect()`

```
/* Declaring the surface. */
SDL_Surface *s;

/* Creating the surface. */
s = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, width, height, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);

/* Filling the surface with red color. */
SDL_FillRect(s, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(s->format, 255, 0, 0));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just realized I forgot the SDL_GetWindowSurface function before SDL_FillRect. Not sure what the difference is between this and SDL_CreateRGBSurface (the latter didn't fully solve the problem: wouldn't show the surface, although it did end the segfault), but will dig into it.
I followed this tutorial, in case someone is interested:
http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/index2.php